# Vue Ag-grid - cellRendererFramework: passing down props

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid

I'm creating some ag-grids for an Vue application and one of the columns requires a reusable component to be rendered with a prop passed down to it. Using cellRendererFramework (as cellRenderer doesn't work with Vue as far as I understand it) There doesn't seem to be a cellRendererFrameworkParams option like cellRendererParams.

```
columnDefs: [
    {
        headerName: 'Column header',
        field: 'field',
        cellRendererFramework: Vue.extend(reusableComponent),
        cellRendererFrameworkParams: { reusableComponentProp: 'test' } // this throws a warning message shown below 
    }
],
```

Warning message:

```
ag-grid: invalid colDef property 'cellRendererFrameworkParams' did you mean any of these: cellRendererFramework,cellRendererParams,pinnedRowCellRendererFramework,pinnedRowCellRendererParams,cellRenderer,cellRenderer,cellRendererSelector,cellEditorFramework
```

On the basis of that, cellRendererFrameworkParams doesn't exist, So does anyone know of a nice work around?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `cellRendererFrameworkParams` try using `cellRendererParams`. Then in your component `reusableComponent`, you can access the `reusableComponentProp` param via `this.params` (e.g. `this.params.reusableComponentProp`).

[vue.js](/questions/tagged/vue.js) [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid)

Comment: please add tags so that it will reach to right users